# How to merge two elements in an array together?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example you have the 2d array Board as shown below:

{0, 2, 4, 2}

{0, 0, 2, 2}

{2, 2, 0, 0}

{0, 5, 0, 2}

You want it to become:

{0, 2, 4, 2}

{0, 0, 4, 0}

{4, 0, 0, 0}

{0, 5, 0, 2}

When there are 2 elements next to each other you need to merge them to make 4 into the left-most place out of those two elements and then make the 2nd element to be 0.
You want to do this with java.

forgot to show my existing loop, this is it below:

```
for (int row = 0; row < Board.length; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col <= Board.length; col++){
       if ((Board[row][col] == Board[row][col +1])){
            Board[row][col] = 2 * Board[row][col];
            Board[row][col + 1] = 0;
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, provide us your tries first, thats the way you should learn most. You basically do not need triple nested looping as you have only 2D array. You should have two (for example) for loops, upper one that goes by rows and second, inner, one that goes by column.

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far, no one will do the whole task for you :-) .
++ What if we have 3 or 4 of the same elements in a row? e.g. { 2, 2, 2 ,2}

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy my existing for loop.

Comment: If there are 3 or for elements in the same row like {2, 2, 2, 2} that would be {4, 0, 4, 0} if there are three like {2, 2, 2, 0} then that would become {4, 0 , 2, 0}

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post with my for loop, I did what Johnczek said but I keep getting an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: @LeninCumin see my answer below, you are getting IndexOutOfBound exception because you are not checking  processing of last column of row. In that case you want to retrieve data of next column (col+1) but that data is not there.

Comment: You said 2 elements next to each other.  What about `[0,2,4,2]`?  That would seem to be `[0,6,0,2]`.  So did you really mean elements of the value `2` next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess that should work. In the loop, you must be careful not to refer to the wrong ( or non-existing) array element.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = new int[][]{{0, 2, 4, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 0, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 0}};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == arr[i][j + 1]) {
                arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j + 1];
                arr[i][j + 1] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, focusing only array values that equal 2.

- iterate the 2D array.
- then iterate over each linear array, checking adjacent values and making the changes.

```
for(int[] arr : v) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 2 && arr[i+1] == 2) {
            arr[i]+= arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = 0;
        }
    }
}

for(int arr[]: v) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

prints

```
[0, 2, 4, 2]
[0, 0, 4, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 5, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I assume that Board variable holds array (quick tip, common convention is to name variable in camelCase (first letter lowercase, then each letter of next work upper, if that variable is constant, then convention is SNAKE_UPPER_CASE)

Your first for is pretty okay, the second one too but it assumes that matrix will be always NxN and will fail if thats not the case or it will not work properly (depending if amount of cols is lower or greater than length of array)

Inside it you dont want to check if the values are equal, you want to check if these values are both equal to 2. And you should check if thats not processing of last column of the row, in that case youll get IndexOutOfBoundException because you want to get value of matrix that is not present.

So with small changes, you will achieve what you want. This code will hopefuly shows my thoughts better

```
public class MergingTwos {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  // Init a matrix
  int[][] array = new int[][] { { 0, 2, 4, 2 }, { 0, 0, 2, 2 }, { 2, 2, 0, 0 }, { 2, 2, 0, 0 }, { 0, 5, 0, 2 }};
  
  // Iterating over each row of matrix, in veriable i, the current X index is stored
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      // Iterating over each column of row, in variable n, the current Y index is stored
      for(int n = 0; n < array[i].length; n++) {
        
        // To prevent index out of bound exception, last element of row wont be processed so as we dont want to proceed if given and next value on row are not 2
        if(n == array[i].length -1 || array[i][n] != 2 || array[i][n+1] != 2) {
            continue;
        }
        
        // To value at given coordinates [i,n] you add values of value on coordinates [i, n+1]
        array[i][n] = array[i][n] + array[i][n+1];
        // And setting next element to 0
        array[i][n+1] = 0;
      }
  }
  
  // Printing the result
  for (int[] x : array) {
    for (int y : x) {
        System.out.print(y + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

}